# Not able to connect to Oracle user

Tags: oracle11g

I have installed Oracle 11g version - Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production.

I have created a user called K_demo. But I am not able to connect to the user using sqlplus. Getting below error.

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Apr 16 10:35:08 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
Enter user-name:**
```

Although I am able to connect from sys using conn

```
SQL> conn K_DEMO/"pass@123"@ORCL
Connected.
SQL> show user;
USER is "K_DEMO"
SQL>
```

what could be the reason?

Comment: have you checked if your user is locked? select username,account_status from dba_users where account_status like '%LOCK%';  if it is you can unlock this way alter user K_DEMO account unlock;

Comment: What is the **exact** command line you use to run sqlplus when you get the first error?

Comment: @catalinetu : The account status is shown as Open.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I am receiving the error whenever I am trying to connect using sqlplus
sqlplus <username>/<password>@ORCL

C:\Users\demo>sqlplus K_DEMO/"pass@123"@ORCL

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Apr 22 12:42:21 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Enter user-name:

Comment: What happens if you do not pass the details on the command line and start sqlplus and then login?

Comment: @grail : Hey thanks, I am able to connect now. 

C:\Users\demo>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Apr 22 13:33:38 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: K_DEMO
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> show user
USER is "K_DEMO"
SQL>

But how can I establish the connection through another program(for eg connect the user using Python)

Comment: I know it is not a long term solution, but try changing your password to not include the '@' and then login without using the quotes, ie. sqlplus K_DEMO/newPass123@ORCL.  You could also try without the db sid as a test too.  My guess would be that the command prompt in Windows might be screwing with the text somehow??